# IIS URL Rewrite to external site

Tags: url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, iis-10, http-status-code-502

I'm about 3 days into this and cannot figure out what the roadblock is. I have an HTTPS site hosted on corporate intranet, that needs to view live H264 feeds from external IP cameras (camera determined by port). The camera does not support HTTPS and browsers block mixed-content. Right now I have the following URL Rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="IP Camera Rewrite" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="camera/site/([0-9]+)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://9.9.9.9:{R:1}/axis-cgi/media.cgi?videocodec=h264" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

I can go to the native URL direct in the browser and the stream works, but when I go to the match URL I get a 502.3 timeout. Not 100% sure how to interpret the FRT log, but I get ErrorCode 2147954402. I don't have any outbound rules, but suspect that might be contributing.

Comment: Mistake 3, https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: The 502.3 means while acting as a proxy ARR was unable to complete the request to the upstream server and subsequently send a response back to the client. This can happen for multiple reasons including , failure to connect to the server , no response from the server, or server took too long to respond (time out), more information about how to troubleshoot this error you can refer to this link: [The operation timed out” with IIS Application Request Routing](https://blogs.iis.net/richma/502-3-bad-gateway-the-operation-timed-out-with-iis-application-request-routing-arr).

Answer (score 0):

ok, I've found it.

I've added SSL cert from dockers webapp to "Trasted Root Certification Authorities", and added domain name used in cert to hosts file

```
127.0.0.1     dockers-webapp
```

reverse proxy starts to work correctly.

--
Pawel

Comment: There is a posibility to reduce security level with ignoring cert errors. This can be done with value in REG key 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\Application Request Routing\Parameters` .
More info on MS KB [ARR: Support Added for WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/arr-support-added-for-winhttpoptionsecurityflags) .